# Nginx reverse proxy and a URL rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I would like to rewrite the URL in a reverse proxy so that it removes the first segment but leaves any following segments intact. I need this to happen before it hits the proxy pass.

Example:

```
/admin/auth/local ----> (REWRITES TO) /auth/local
/admin/auth/register -------> (REWRITES TO) /auth/register
```

My Location block:

```
  location /admin {
        #add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_read_timeout                 30;
        proxy_buffers 64 8k;
        rewrite /admin / break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
```

I tried the following with no luck:

```
rewrite /admin / break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts here. First one is how nginx routes incoming requests via `proxy_pass`.

There one can map incoming requests for `/` to backend with `/admin/` prefix with the following configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/admin/;
}
```

No `rewrite` statement is needed.

Second part is the URLs that are generated by the application that is running at `127.0.0.1:9000`. You need to configure that application to generate URLs without the `/admin` prefix to have URLs that match nginx routing setup.

Nginx cannot reliably do this change on the content generated by the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to add your first segment(admin) to the proxy pass.

```
proxy_pass http://www.example.com/admin/;
```

Comment: When I update this I am still getting the /admin segment being passed through where I want to remove the admin and retain any trailing segments

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following snippet. Works for me.

```
location ~* /admin/(.*) {
  ...
  rewrite .* /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

`(.*)` from the first line is retrieved in the block as `$1`. The idea is to retrieve the URI after `admin/`, and replace all with that URI.